# Python 3 and TKinter - Cannot get Entry value thru my_var.get()

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to pass an Entry field value to a second function, but I only get an empty string. Can anyone tell me what i'm missing? Here's my code:

```
def fenetre_changer_nom_joueur(self,joueur):

    self.changer_nom_main = Tk()
    self.changer_nom_main.geometry('300x200')
    self.string_nom_joueur = StringVar()
    Entry(self.changer_nom_main, textvariable=self.string_nom_joueur).grid(row=2, column=2, sticky=W)
    Button(self.changer_nom_main, text="Enregistrer",command = lambda: self.changer_nom_joueur(joueur), padx=10,
           pady=10).grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=W)
    Button(self.changer_nom_main, text="Fermer", width=13,
           command=lambda: self.fermer_fenetre(self.changer_nom_main), padx=10,
           pady=10).grid(row=3, column=2, sticky=W)
    self.changer_nom_main.mainloop()


def changer_nom_joueur(self, joueur):
    """
   This is where I'm tring to get the Entry field value. But the .get() return an emptry string
    """
    temp = self.string_nom_joueur.get()
    joueur.nom = temp
```

Comment: your code works fine for me. When I type something in and click the "Enregistrer" button, `temp` is set to what I typed. Since you didn't show a complete working example, it's possible that when I guessed at the rest of the code I guessed wrong.

Answer (score -1):

```
Entry(self.changer_nom_main, textvariable=self.string_nom_joueur).....
```

This line sets the textvariable to self.string_nom_joueur. I think what you want to do is the opposite. You want self.string_nom_joueur to be textvariable.

You will first need to assign the Entry to a variable i.e.:

```
self.entrynamefield = Entry(self.changer_nom_main, textvariable=self.string_nom_joueur).....
```

Then you need to use the .set() method to set self.string_nom_joeuer:

```
self.string_nom_joeuer.set(self.entrynamefield.get())
```

After you have set your string variable, your function changer_nom_joueur will have something to ".get()"

Comment: if you are using the `textvariable` attribute, you don't need to assign the widget to a variable.

Comment: How do you call the textvariable when it is not assigned? If you have more than one entry widget how do you differentiate the textvariable?

Comment: I don't understand your question. You don't "call" a textvariable. It is an attribute of a widget. When you type in the widget, it automatically updates the value in the associated textvariable. You can get the value by calling `.get()` on the variable (eg: `self.string_nom_joueur.get()`). If you have more than one entry widget, you will typically have more than one `StringVar`. That, or you don't ever use `textvariable` and always just directly get the value from the widget.

Comment: Ah got it, that makes more sense now